# Debugging CMV Disclaimer widget error?

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

I have been trying to get the Disclaimer widget found [here](https://github.com/tmcgee/cmv-widgets/blob/master/widgets/Disclaimer/README.md) to function with a relatively normal CMV application. I have reviewed the several other posts on Stack Exchange troubleshooting this widget but have had no luck.

I've copied all the files to my project directory in what I think is the correct location and added the requisite configuration to viewer.js.

When I load my page, the disclaimer does not appear and I see the following errors in Firebug:

[image: disclaimer error]

The code I am using is copied directly from the developer samples, so I must either have a file in wrong location or have something configured incorrectly. When I comment out the disclaimer widget config in viewer.js, the errors disappear in Firebug.

Comment: Please include all errors as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searchers by anyone else encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be one of 2 issues:

1. You perhaps did not copy Disclaimer.js and the Disclaimer folder into your `dijit` folder referenced in the error. The Disclaimer widget does not come with CMV. You have to get it from my GitHub repo and copyall the necessary files to that folder. Alternatively, like demonstrated in my repo, use a separate folder for the custom/contributed widgets that do not come with CMV.
2. You may be using an Operating System/Web Server that is case-sensitive. The Disclaimer.js file has a capital `D`. If this is the case, you will need to change the reference in viewer.js to `gis/dijit/Disclaimer.js`